# VBA_Error '1004' while using the InStr Function

Tags: vba, excel

Good morning,

I'd like to use a For cycle to compare two sheets' content, and do something if the condition is satisfied.

```
For j = 1 To ligne_Brouillon

    If InStr(Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, 7).Text, Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 18).Text) <> 0 Then  'compare two cells' content

        For k = 8 To colonne_brouillon

            If InStr(Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, k).Text, Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 20).Text) <> 0 Then  'if the first cell contents the keyword
                Sheets("Data").Cells(i, ma_Colonne).Text = Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, k).Text
            End If

        Next

    End If

Next
```

but I've met the error '1004' when I tried to run. I don't know who to fix this. Please give me some advices if you got some ideas.
Thanks in advance.

---

Sure, my object is to fill a table of quality control, which contains the name of tests and the results. The tests and the results are reserved separately in some files.
My work is to fill the table when I have a new test. And for each point of test, the criteria are the same (such as the colour, the form etc.), and I just need to fill the correct cell with the correct result.
I want to open a new sheet and fill it with all the results and then fill the table with this new sheet. I think that could easier.

Here is the complete code:

```
Private Sub Button_Importer_Click()

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Brouillon"

    list_de_controle = "TEXT;" & listPath  'here I have a list to open

    For i = 1 To nombre_Ligne  'From the first to the last line in "Data"sheet

        mon_Objet = Cells(i, 15).Text + "_" + Cells(i, 17).Text
        Open listPath For Input As #1  'open the list of tests

        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, nom_de_Fich
            If InStr(nom_de_Fich, mon_Objet) > 0 Then 
           'if this file is the correct test file I want to open

                mfile = Dir(nom_de_Fich & "*.*")
                If mfile <> "" Then
                    GoTo_Brouillon  'go to the new sheet

                    Open nom_de_Fich For Input As #2  'open the file
                        Insérer_contenu
                    Close #2

                End If

                compléter_Tableau  'with this new sheet, I will fill the table

            End If

        Loop
        Close #1

    Next

End Sub
```

and for the Sub compéter_Tableau():

```
Public Sub compléter_Tableau()

    Dim ligne_Brouillon
    Sheets("Brouillon").Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    ligne_Brouillon = Selection.Row
    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
    colonne_brouillon = Selection.Column

    For j = 1 To ligne_Brouillon

        If InStr(Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, 7).Text, Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 18).Text) <> 0 Then

            For k = 8 To colonne_brouillon

                If InStr(Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, k).Text, Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 20).Text) <> 0 Then
                    Sheets("Data").Cells(i, ma_Colonne).Text = Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, k).Text
                End If

            Next

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: `Sheets _("Brouillon")` remove the underscore and space, same with `Sheets _("Data")`.  You use an `_` where you are splitting code onto multiple lines

Comment: You also don't appear to set `i` to anything in the shown code. Is it defined previously?

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't have these underscores in my macro, just when I posted this issue, this line is too long so I add an underscore. But is seems that it can't work just like in VBA to cut a line into two parts.

Comment: And yes, 'i' has been defined before, in another cycle, this is a part of a function, and I want to use it in the other Sub.

Comment: You want to use `i` in a different sub to where it was declared and defined?  If you are not passing it from one to the other (or have it publicly declared) then it will be out of scope in the above code and will cause this error.  Maybe you could post the whole code so it's clearer what's defined where and how?

Comment: I've post the code as a new answer. And I think i can work in this new Sub, can't it? I've tried once to debug.Print i in this Sub and it works. But I'm not sure if it really works or just a coincidence?

Comment: No.  `i` is declared inside `Button_Importer_Click` and is limited in scope to that Sub.  Should you want to reference it in `compléter_Tableau` then you will need to **pass** it in there.  This will be causing your error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button_Importer_Click()

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Brouillon"

    list_de_controle = "TEXT;" & listPath  'here I have a list to open

    For i = 1 To nombre_Ligne  'From the first to the last line in "Data"sheet

        mon_Objet = Cells(i, 15).Text + "_" + Cells(i, 17).Text
        Open listPath For Input As #1  'open the list of tests

        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, nom_de_Fich
            If InStr(nom_de_Fich, mon_Objet) > 0 Then 
           'if this file is the correct test file I want to open

                mfile = Dir(nom_de_Fich & "*.*")
                If mfile <> "" Then
                    GoTo_Brouillon  'go to the new sheet

                    Open nom_de_Fich For Input As #2  'open the file
                        Insérer_contenu
                    Close #2

                End If

                compléter_Tableau i  ' pass i into the other sub so it can be used

            End If

        Loop
        Close #1

    Next
    End Sub
```

and change the second Sub to accept the parameter so it knows what `i` is:

```
Public Sub compléter_Tableau(byVal i)

    Dim ligne_Brouillon
    ligne_Brouillon = Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(Sheets("Brouillon").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    colonne_brouillon = Sheets("Brouillon").Cells("A", Sheets("Brouillon").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = 1 To ligne_Brouillon

        If InStr(Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, 7).Text, Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 18).Text) <> 0 Then

            For k = 8 To colonne_brouillon

                If InStr(Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, k).Text, Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 20).Text) <> 0 Then
                    Sheets("Data").Cells(i, ma_Colonne).Text = Sheets("Brouillon").Cells(j, k).Text
                End If

            Next

        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

I've also simplified your method for selecting the last row and column; try to avoid the use of `ActiveCell`, and `Select`s as they are not required in virtually any instance and slow things down

Comment: Thank you! But the line 'compléter_Tableau i' cause an error of compilation : Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: What is the value of `i` at the point the error occurs?  Step through the code execution using the F8 key and keep an eye on the values

Comment: i is vide. But the first file has been opened and put into the the new sheet. I don't understand

Comment: Sorry, what's "vide"?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's empty.

Comment: That's not possible, surely?  To get to the function call `i` has to have been set to a value by the loop construct.  How are you checking its value?

Comment: I tried to use F8, but it doesn't works well when I chose the list to open. So I just run it and when it's blocked, the local variable window shows me i is empty.

Comment: Add the command `Debug.Print i` directly before and after the function call and add a breakpoint (click in the margin) on the row with the function call.  Make sure you have the Immediate Window showing; VBA will print the value of `i` into it before and after the call.  If you wait till the code halts, `i` will lose its value

Comment: Oh I see, i is 1 for the first cycle in For. But it's not sent into the Sub compléter_Tableau, when it came to this sub, i turns to empty.

Comment: Really?  Sounds like you have not passed in the variable?  Does your code match my answer?

Comment: Right at the very top of the code window, outside any `Sub`, add `Option Explicit` - this will require you to ensure all variables are declared before you use them and mayhelp point to what's going wrong here

Comment: I've defined a variable i at the very beggining, like Public i as Integer, and it seems work? I'm not sure because I've met another error 1004 : not set the Text property of the Range class. So i is good I think?

Comment: use `.Value` instead of `.Text`

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it laterly, now I have a course to take, have a nice day and see you later!